# How to fix Einstein Email Recommendations (Content Catalog) displaying same results for all users?

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, einstein-recommendations, tracking

I saw a similar unresolved question from a few years ago and SF support have not been able to explain why this might happen, so turning here - you're my last hope!

FAQ:
DEs for profiles and content views are populating correctly.
User pages views and affinities are visible in reporting and look correct.
Content ID matches the Catalog.
I have removed all rules.
I have 2 separate display blocks testing different combinations of scenarios but always seeing hte same 4 results.

Payload: removed a little info but hopefully nothing important to diagnosis:

```json
{
    "category": "Futures",
    "ContentID": "/education/courses/introduction-to-futures/mark-to-market.html",
    "item": "/education/courses/introduction-to-futures/mark-to-market.html",
    "title": "Mark-to-Market",
    "url": "https://www.website.com/education/courses/introduction-to-futures/mark-to-market.html",
    "referrer": "",
    "user_info": {
        "email": "**[address@domain.com]**"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you don't write anything about for how long you have had the tracking configured, and how many impressions each of your contacts have generated. It The uniqueness of the offers provided increases significantly over time.

If you are convinced that the data volume should be sufficient for your recommendations to be more personalised than they are, you could try to use the debugging option of recommendations. It is not officially documented, so it is more: "good luck" approach.

You simply replace .json with .explain in the feed with recommended products, allowing you to confirm the basis for why the specific items have been selected.

```
Example: https://MID.recs.igodigital.com/a/v2/MID/INSERT_PAGE_NAME/recommend.explain
```

You will then see output similar to the example below:

```json
{
    "scenarios": [
        {
            "name": "topenjoyed",
            "code": "Home_TopEnjoyed",
            "score": 990,
            "getmores": 1,
            "for_target": "OurMostBoughtProducts",
            "items": [
                "ABC-93710600001",
                "ABC-86594971",
                "ABC-94212000003"
            ],
            "filters": [],
            "status": "returned"
        },
        {
            "name": "topenjoyed",
            "code": "Home_TopEnjoyed",
            "score": 900,
            "getmores": 1,
            "for_target": "InSeason",
            "items": ["ABC-87847461", "ABC-87843491", "ABC-87847471"],
            "filters": [],
            "status": "returned"
        },
        {
            "name": "topenjoyed",
            "code": "Home_TopEnjoyed",
            "score": 800,
            "getmores": 1,
            "for_target": "NewProducts",
            "items": [
                "ABC-19025001",
                "ABC-87906121",
                "ABC-24690301"
            ],
            "filters": [],
            "status": "returned"
        },
        {
            "name": "topenjoyed",
            "code": "Home_TopEnjoyed",
            "score": 700,
            "getmores": 2,
            "for_target": "MostRelevantPromotedProducts",
            "items": [
                "ABC-35926501",
                "ABC-30965601",
                "ABC-22645201"
            ],
            "filters": [],
            "status": "returned"
        },
        {
            "name": "topsellers",
            "code": "Home_MostPopular",
            "score": 1000,
            "getmores": 2,
            "for_target": "OurMostBoughtProducts",
            "items": [],
            "filters": [],
            "status": "rejected"
        },
        {
            "name": "topsellers",
            "code": "Home_MostPopular",
            "score": 920,
            "getmores": 2,
            "for_target": "InSeason",
            "items": [],
            "filters": [],
            "status": "rejected"
        },
        {
            "name": "topviews",
            "code": "Home_MostViewed",
            "score": 910,
            "getmores": 2,
            "for_target": "InSeason",
            "items": [
                "ABC-89673861",
                "ABC-88148871",
                "ABC-99403401050"
            ],
            "filters": [],
            "status": "rejected"
        },
        {
            "name": "topsellers",
            "code": "Home_MostPopular",
            "score": 820,
            "getmores": 2,
            "for_target": "NewProducts",
            "items": [],
            "filters": [],
            "status": "rejected"
        },
        {
            "name": "topviews",
            "code": "Home_MostViewed",
            "score": 810,
            "getmores": 2,
            "for_target": "NewProducts",
            "items": [
                "ABC-89673861",
                "ABC-88148871",
                "ABC-99403401050"
            ],
            "filters": [],
            "status": "rejected"
        },
        {
            "name": "topsellers",
            "code": "Home_MostPopular",
            "score": 720,
            "getmores": 2,
            "for_target": "MostRelevantPromotedProducts",
            "items": [],
            "filters": [],
            "status": "rejected"
        },
        {
            "name": "topviews",
            "code": "Home_MostViewed",
            "score": 710,
            "getmores": 2,
            "for_target": "MostRelevantPromotedProducts",
            "items": [
                "ABC-89673861",
                "ABC-88148871",
                "ABC-99403401050"
            ],
            "filters": [],
            "status": "rejected"
        },
        {
            "name": "topgrossing",
            "code": "Home_TopGrossing",
            "score": 1,
            "getmores": 0,
            "for_target": null,
            "items": null,
            "filters": [],
            "status": "available"
        },
        {
            "name": "topviews",
            "code": "Home_MostViewed",
            "score": 1,
            "getmores": 0,
            "for_target": null,
            "items": null,
            "filters": [],
            "status": "available"
        },
        {
            "name": "topsellers",
            "code": "Home_MostPopular",
            "score": 1,
            "getmores": 0,
            "for_target": null,
            "items": null,
            "filters": [],
            "status": "available"
        }
    ],
    "filters": [
        {
            "type": "emphasize_tags",
            "params": [{}],
            "block_given?": false,
            "priority": 0,
            "waslocal": true,
            "excluded_skus": null
        },
        {
            "type": "exclude",
            "params": [{ "ct": ["asset", "content", "banner"] }],
            "block_given?": false,
            "priority": 0,
            "waslocal": true,
            "excluded_skus": []
        }
    ],
    "divs": [
        { "size": "1..16", "target": "OurMostBoughtProducts" },
        {
            "size": "1..16",
            "target": "InSeason",
            "filters": [
                {
                    "type": "include",
                    "params": [{ "st": "Christmas" }, null],
                    "block_given?": false,
                    "priority": 0,
                    "waslocal": true,
                    "excluded_skus": [
                        "ABC-94212300001",
                        "ABC-46054901",
                        "ABC-32529101",
                        "ABC-87906081",
                        "ABC-54878201"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "size": "1..16",
            "target": "NewProducts",
            "filters": [
                {
                    "type": "include",
                    "params": [{ "ne": "Y" }, null],
                    "block_given?": false,
                    "priority": 0,
                    "waslocal": true,
                    "excluded_skus": [
                        "ABC-89673861",
                        "ABC-88148871",
                        "ABC-99403401050",
                        "ABC-87879261",
                        "ABC-87842451"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "size": "1..16",
            "target": "MostRelevantPromotedProducts",
            "filters": [
                {
                    "type": "include",
                    "params": [{ "ioo": "Y" }, null],
                    "block_given?": false,
                    "priority": 0,
                    "waslocal": true,
                    "excluded_skus": [
                        "ABC-87842441",
                        "ABC-87884171",
                        "ABC-93710500001",
                        "ABC-87905821",
                        "ABC-87842491",
                        "ABC-87842451"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "errors": [],
    "weights": {},
    "page": "general",
    "referer": null
}
```

Comment: Hi Lukas, Thanks for your speedy response. I think your response may be specific to Web Recommendations, which we haven't even turned on at this stage - I tried to put the explain code in an email but was not getting anything. Also, this is a content catalog - not particularly large (~50 articles) for our initial testing and we have users who do have defined  affinities that I should think would affect their result?

Comment: Well, you should still be able to use the web recommendations to validate the recommendations shown to individual recipients, just add the identifier to the URL requesting that recommendation set and compare the *.explain* details